# extract the second to last item for column with dot splitting

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have the following columns in data frame:

```
  `'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.LongIntMapTest.copyTest'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.LongIntMapTest.get'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.LongIntMapTest.preizedPut'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.LongIntMapTest.put'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.LongIntMapTest.remove'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.parallel_eager_ec'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.parallel_eager_ec_hand_coded'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.parallel_lazy_ec'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.parallel_lazy_ec_hand_coded'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.parallel_lazy_jdk'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.parallel_lazy_scala'
  'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.parallel_lazy_scala_hand_coded'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.serial_eager_ec'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.serial_eager_ec_hand_coded'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.serial_eager_scala'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.serial_lazy_ec'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.serial_lazy_jdk'
   'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.FunctionalInterfaceTest.serial_lazy_scala'`
```

As we can see the length is different, I want to add a new column to the data frame named as a class, this column contains the second to last part of the name. all the values are separated by dot. 
So the expected output will be a dataframe with 2 columns, the first one is the Benchmark(the one that attached in this post), and the second one is the Class (the second to last item in the values of Benchmark like 'org.eclipse.collections.impl.jmh.LongIntMapTest`in the first row`FunctionalInterfaceTest` in the sixth one )

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.split('\.').str[-2]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've invested your answer by modifying the code you've attached as the following `df['Class'] = df['Benchmark'].str.split('\.').str[-2]` So I drop n parameter in the split function and I add -2 to the str instead of -1 because I want the 2'nd to the last item @jezrael